# Tampermonkey подключить локальный js файл

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

`// @require  file://C:/js.js`

Дебаггер говорит `Tampermonkey: couldn't load @require from URL file://C:/js.js`

возможно ли подключить локальный файл?

Comment: Если вы используете Firefox, то скорее всего это связано с https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266960

Comment: @RTK использую opera

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен. нужно было в настройках расширения включить"доступ к файловым ссылкам"